# How to sort a list of objects from a parent object using a for loop Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I'm using Spring MVC and I'm trying to sort a `list` of objects that I'm getting from the parent object.  Right now I have a `Course` object that has a list of `Posts`.  I also have a `User` that's subscribed to `Courses` and I'm using a `for loop` to grab all the `posts` for each `Course` that the user is subscribed to.

I want this to return in a news feed sort of way, and right now it's showing the first `post` at the top and new `posts` are added to the bottom.

In other parts of my application I have a `findByObjectOrderbyIdDesc` which returns the objects in chronological order the way I want, but that's when I use a repository, and I'm not doing that here.  So I'm not sure how to do this.

I'll show some of my code, so you guys can see what I'm talking about

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="{user}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String userPageGet (ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user)
{
    List<StudySet> studySets = studySetRepo.findByUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("studySets", studySets);

    List<Course> courses = courseRepo.findByUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("courses", courses);

    Set<Post> posts = new TreeSet<>();

    for (Course course : courses) {
        posts.addAll(course.getPosts());
    }
    model.addAttribute("posts", posts);

    return "user";
}
```

If anyone can see a solution to my issue and could let me know that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry what is the question?

Comment: Does Post implement Comparable<Post>?  If so, it should sort by that automatically.  If not, you could write a Comparator<Post> for it and construct the TreeSet with that.

Comment: @GregoryBush Post does implement comparable, but they don't show up in the right order

Comment: @FarazDurrani the posts are being sorted in the wrong direction, I want the most recent posts to be at the top of the page, but the first post stays at the top of the page, and the most recents are added to the bottom

Comment: why can't you just use `findByObjectOrderbyIdDesc` in this part of code as well as in other parts?

Comment: @KenBekov because I wasn't using a repository to get the `posts` I was using the `get` method from my `Course` class and I was using the loop to get all the `posts` for each `course`.  So I didn't see a way to be able to use `findByObjectOrderbyIdDesc`, but I got it fixed using the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the question:

> @FarazDurrani the posts are being sorted in the wrong direction, I want the most recent posts to be at the top of the page, but the first post stays at the top of the page, and the most recents are added to the bottom

Then:

You `Post` is obvious implementing the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (if not you cold not add it to an `TreeSet` without explicit `Comparator`).

A `TreeSet` sort its items, but you want it it in the inverse order:

You have a lot of options:

- Invert the `compareTo(T o)` method in you `Post` class (multiply the result with `-1`), but I guess this is not the best solution, because it would affect all other functions that base on `Post`s comparable implementation.
- Initialize the `TreeSet` with an explicit `Comparator`. Because your `Post` class already implements `Comparable` that you just want to invert, it become easy:

  ```
  new TreeSet(new Comarator<Post>{
     public in compare(Post o1, Post o2){
         //o2.compareTo(o1) instead of o1.compareTo(o2) makes it reverse
          return o2.compareTo(o1);
     }
  })
  ```

  *Thats the way I would choose.*
- use a `List` and [`Collections.reverse(list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) function:

  ```
  Set<Post> posts = new TreeSet<>();
  for (Course course : courses) {
      posts.addAll(course.getPosts());
  }

  List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>(posts);
  Collections.reverse(postList);

  model.addAttribute("posts", postList);
  ```

Comment: @Ralph you already have 61k reputations let newbies like me answer such easy questions :P